# How to clean up input data in a Django view to avoid CSRF?

Tags: python, django, django-views, csrf, django-csrf

Lets say, in a view, I use input data to create an instance of a Model in my Django project.

```
def create_post(request, message):
    post = Post.objects.create(message=message)
    post.save()
```

Now, the problem is, the 'message' is coming from sources which may be unsavory, that is, a plugin that makes AJAX requests to my API. If it was a django form, I could have just used `{% csrf_token %}` and cleared the issue, but, I want to do this in my view. How do I do this?

Note, please don't suggest adding csrf protection in my Javscript code, because that will not work for my case.

Thanks!

Comment: Why will adding a CSRF in your javascript not work?  It should be easy enough by injecting the CSRF token into the template as a javascript variable.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [`csrf_exempt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt), but I'm not sure and if it were I wouldn't be comfortable in adding it as an answer.

Comment: @AdamBarnes - Uh because its a plugin that will be used on different 3rd party websites. Am I missing something here? Can a plugin like that still have csrf on them? I must admit, I don't understand this thing very well.

Comment: @Sayse I think he's more after [requires_csrf_token](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.requires_csrf_token), but I'm not sure.  Tahmid Khan Nafee, what do you mean by "unsavory" sources?  If your code will be used as a plugin on third party websites, then the entire concept of CSRF makes no sense, as you _want_ to accept requests from other sites.